# How to show array content in a textarea?

Tags: angularjs, arrays, textarea

I'm trying to show the content of an array of String into a textarea.

Basically i have a select on which user can choose his output, and when he choose, the array is populated with the selected String.

Here is my HTML:

```
<select  class="form-control" id="dispatchOutput" ng-model="dispatchOutput" 
  ng-options="item as (item.output | uppercase) for item in searchFilterDispatcher.params" 
  ng-change="updateOutput()">

<textarea class="form-control" ng-model="selectedOutput" id="selectedOoutput" 
                               ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false" rows="10"></textarea>
```

and here my JS:

```
$scope.selectedOutput = [];
$scope.updateOutput = function(){
    $scope.selectedOutput.push($scope.dispatchOutput.output);
}
```

My textarea stays completely blank.
Where did I get wrong?

Comment: What went wrong? What does "wrong" look like? How is it supposed to look?

Answer (score 0):

change your text area code to :-

```
<textarea class="form-control" ng-model="$parent.selectedOutput" id="selectedOoutput" 
                               ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: the result is the same, blank

Comment: @Anon , are you getting value in `$scope.dispatchOutput.output`?

Comment: yep, the string